# Using co coroutine library client-side in browser?

Tags: javascript, client-side, coroutine, co

How can I use

[co coroutine library](https://github.com/tj/co)

in a client application in the browser?

Comment: Just use it? The browser needs to support ES6 generator functions, though. If it doesn't, you need to use a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just for test. DO NOT USE in Production.

```
(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/co/master/index.js',
        async: false,
    }).done(function (source) {
        var module = {exports: {}};
        var exports = module.exports;
        eval(source); // run the source of co
        window.co = module.exports; // bind co to window
        console.log(window.co);
    }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, statusText) {
        console.log(textStatus, statusText);
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, you'll need to transpile your code (using babel with the [regenerator plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/) ) , and it's working fine !